# I am looking for suggestions for better way of writing my code as I know its not too efficient program gets votes and adds to count

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

At the bottom I am working on the function vote, which when accessing candidates[i].name and making it equal to the input (name) for ex. ./plurality (name of the file) Alice bob jones and then inputting for name = Alice, it returns false rather than following the line candidates[0].name = Alice == name therefore adding to the vote count.

I am struggling to understand why it goes through my if statement from i = 0 to i = 50ish and doesn't equate Alice to  Alice. Sorry if this is noob question I appreciate any help!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)               // this is the part *** im confused about
{
    // TODO
    //printf("%s\n", name);
    //printf("%s\n", candidates[0].name);
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(candidates); j++)
    {
        if (candidates[j].name == name)
        {
            candidates[j].votes = candidates[j].votes + 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", candidates[0].votes);
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Printing multiple times and using a while loop however using a while loop led to the problem of having a name not in the candidates array at all and therefore running infinitely.

Comment: Not only comparing strings problem, but the number of candidates is not the same as the number of bytes in the array of structs called 'candidates'...

Comment: Oh yeah i totally forgot about that!!!!! thank you so much